# Block Network access for Microsoft Excel

Tags: windows, networking, microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a macro that is stuck on running and has frozen my Excel.

Basically its a loop through roughly 80000 rows performing SQL queries on each row with ADO.DB

Save disabling the network card, is there any other way I can disable network access to Excel to throw a network exception and break the loop?

Comment: Just kill Excel in Task Manager, or try pressing Ctrl+Break to halt execution

Comment: Ctrl Break doesn't do anything and I'd like to avoid killing Excel if possible to prevent data loss, and also so I can see where my loop is jamming up

Comment: How about unplugging your ethernet cable or turning off Wi-Fi? So you are doing 80,000 queries, one at a time?  Are you doing the initial connection setup once outside of the loop, and closing it after the loop (eventually) finishes?

Comment: @MarkStewart i probably didnt make it clear in my question but this is running on a terminal server so pulling out the network cable is not really an option. And yes, connection is opened at the start and closed at the end of the loop.

Comment: Can you not kill the correlated SPID\transaction at the SQL server level instead? Can you show your query logic to an edit in your question and clarify what type of SQL server technology this is hitting behind the scenes. I would look at the query from the SQL side and see if there's an issue with the way it's written at that level. If you can show the query logic you are using and stating if you're using MS SQL, MySQL, etc. that may help you get a more accurate answer from people.

Comment: Have you tried pressing the keys: `ctrl` + `alt` + `break` ?